# Angular ngModel of input is bound incorrectly

Tags: angular

I have created a tags input field as an own component in Angular, but have run into a an issue. The input field used in the component is bindings it's value incorrectly.

Whenever I type in the input field, the `ngModel`-setter is called with the value of the input field. Why is that? The input field is suppose to bind to the filter property (which is does as well) and not the ngModel property.

The template:

```
<div class="si-tags-input">
    ...
    <input [(ngModel)]="filter"/>
</div>
```

The logic:

```
export class SITagsInputComponent {
    filter = "";
    selectedTags = [];

    @Input() get ngModel(){
        return this.selectedTags;
    }
    @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();
    set ngModel(val){
        console.log("val", val);

        this.selectedTags = val;
        this.ngModelChange.emit(this.selectedTags);
    }
    ...
}
```

I use the component like this:

```
<si-tags-input [(ngModel)]="target_locations" [available-tags]="locations" ngDefaultControl></si-tags-input>
```

Comment: I'd guess the value of the input field is being picked up because the `ngModel` directive is binding into that via the control value accessor for input fields.  

I haven't seen the use of your own 'ngModel' get/set properties on a component - might that cause unpredictable behaviour?

For custom components I have implemented `ControlValueAccessor` and then used that component with the `ngModel` directive - as described [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html).

Comment: I tried implementing the `ControlValueAccessor` interface, with it's required methods, but got the same issue. It doesn't seem to matter what I bind the input field to, I can remove the `[(ngModel)]` attribute and the issue remains. It seems like the ngModel property of my component is making some kind if binding to my inner input field.

Comment: Since I needed to find a solution I have gone from using the ngModel attribute, to using a custom attribute `selected-tags` instead, and then it's working fine. However I'd still like to learn how to resolve this *properly*

Comment: can you create a plunker

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
<input [ngModel]="filter"/>
```

Comment: I need the two way data binding, which is why this wont work for me.